# query column names for a single row where value is null?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm attempting to return all of the column names for a single row where the value is null. I can parse the entire row afterward but curious if there's a function that I can leverage.

I can return a JSON object containing key value pairs where the value is *not* null using `row_to_json()` and `json_strip_nulls` where conditional references a single unique row:

```
SELECT json_strip_nulls(row_to_json(t))
   FROM table t where t.id = 123
```

Is there a function or simple way to accomplish the inverse of this, returning all of the keys (column names) with null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a primary key or unique column(s). In the example `id` is unique:

```
with my_table(id, col1, col2, col3) as (
values
    (1, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
    (2, 'a', null, null),
    (3, null, 'b', 'c')
)

select id, array_agg(key) as null_columns
from my_table t
cross join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t))
where value is null
group by id

 id | null_columns 
----+--------------
  2 | {col2,col3}
  3 | {col1}
(2 rows)
```

`key` and `value` are default columns returned by the function `jsonb_each_text().` See [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the JSON approach might work. First transform the rows to a JSON object with `row_ro_json()`. Then expand the JSON objects back to a set using `json_each_text()`. You can now filter for `NULL` values and use aggregation to get the columns, that contain `NULL`.

I don't know what output format you want. `json_object_agg()` is the "complement" to your `json_strip_nulls()`/`row_to_json()` approach. But you may also want a JSON array (`json_agg`), just an array (`array_agg()`) or a comma separated string list (`string_agg()`).

```
SELECT json_object_agg(jet.k, jet.v),
       json_agg(jet.k),
       array_agg(jet.k),
       string_agg(jet.k, ',')
       FROM elbat t
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL row_to_json(t) rtj(j)
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_each_text(rtj.j) jet(k, v)
       WHERE jet.v IS NULL
       GROUP BY rtj.j::text;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=4052984a9b360a117c6f263b63689d47)